# R and HTML chunk error in Text, what can i do?

Tags: html, error-handling, chunks

I don't understand the error message from this chunk.
can someone explain it to me?

i thought it was the letter ä but even if i remove it the chunk doesn't load and the render stops there. But that was not the problem.

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHx2j.jpg)

```
#| label: lala
dfti$Gewicht_Vater[dfti$Gewicht_Vater == 9]                              <- NA
dfti$Größe_Vater[dfti$Größe_Vater == 9]                                  <- NA
dfti$Gewicht_Mutter[dfti$Gewicht_Mutter == 9]                            <- NA
dfti$Größe_Mutter[dfti$Größe_Mutter == 9]                                <- NA
dfti$Gewicht_Kind[dfti$Gewicht_Kind == 99]                               <- NA
dfti$Größe_Kind[dfti$Größe_Kind == 9]                                    <- NA
dfti$Schulbildung_Mutter[dfti$Schulbildung_Mutter == 9]                  <- NA
dfti$Größe_Wohnung[dfti$Größe_Wohnung == 9]                              <- NA
dfti$Gravidität[dfti$Gravidität == 9]                                    <- NA
dfti$Schwangerschaftdauer_Wochen[dfti$Schwangerschaftdauer_Wochen == 99] <- NA
dfti$Stilldauer_Monate[dfti$Stilldauer_Monate == 999]                    <- NA
dfti$Schwangerschaftsdauer_Tage[dfti$Schwangerschaftsdauer_Tage == 9]    <- NA
```

```
ERROR: 
label: lala
Quitting from lines 134-147 (XXXX-XXX-HausarbeitR-Anleitung.qmd) 
Fehler in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:2:8: unerwartete Eingabe
1: dfti$Gewicht_Vater[dfti$Gewicht_Vater == 9]                              <- NA
2: dfti$Gr�
          ^
Ruft auf: .main ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

Ausführung angehalten
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question. Don't post it as text, copy paste it and add it as a code block!

Comment: Thanks for your request! You mean like this, @cloned?